# How to replace this preg_replace by preg_replace_callback for php 5.6 compatibility

Tags: php, php-5.6, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to update some code that is 20 years old to be compatible with php 5.6. One of the major changes I'm facing is the deprecation of "/e" modifier in preg_replace.

For most of them, I just replaced it by preg_replace_callback, removed "/e" and used a function as a second arg.

But I'm facing a case where it doesn't work and after a lot of things tried, I'm still not able to reproduce how it was working before.

```
function _munge_input($template) {
    $orig[] = '/<\?plugin.*?\?>/se';
    $repl[] = "\$this->_mungePlugin('\\0')";

    $orig[] = '/<\?=(.*?)\?>/s';
    $repl[] = '<?php $this->_print(\1);?>';

    return preg_replace($orig, $repl, $template);
}
```

I tried to replace $repl by :

```
function ($matches) use ($repl) {
    return $repl;
}
```

(or even to include the $repl assignment directly in the function)

with the first $repl assignment modified :

```
$repl[] = "\$this->_mungePlugin('$matches[0]')";
```

But it still doesn't work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately, `preg_replace_callback_array` was introduced in PHP 7. Try [this code](https://ideone.com/DV17sH). Not sure you need `return '<?php ' . $this->_print($matches[1]) . '?>';` in the second case, probably, `return $this->_print($matches[1]);` will do.

Comment: I don't really understand why but with this initial code :
$repl[0] = $repl[] = "\$this->_mungePlugin('\\0')";
and $repl[1] = '<?php $this->_print(\1);?>';
So, I'm not sure the code you gave me will return the same result.

Comment: Ok I will give pieces of information asap

Comment: Probably it is due to `$this` inside the callback, try https://ideone.com/6KkJ47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it works with this code :

```
function _munge_input($template) {
    $that = $this;
    $template = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<\?plugin.*?\?>/s',
        function ($matches) use ($that) {
            return $that->_mungePlugin($matches[0]);
        },
        $template
    );

    $template = preg_replace('/<\?=(.*?)\?>/s', '<?php $this->_print(\1);?>', $template);

    return $template;
}
```

The issue was the use of $this in another scope as you told me.

Big thanks to wiktor stribiżew. Your code was better but the second part was not concerned by /e so I changed back to preg_replace.

Best.